# How should an Ajax endpoint respond to a non-ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I am in the process of writing the backend  to respond to ajax queries. I am using Codeigniter, and my controller is made up of a bunch of these functions.

```
public function name_change()
{
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        //Grab the Inputs
        //Do something
        //Respond
    }
    else
    {

    }           
}
```

my only question is how should i handle the case where it is not an Ajax request? There is no reason that these controller functions should be accessed by a non ajax request. The options that i can think of are.

- Send No Response
- throw up an error page (i assume i would use Status Code 200 or 403)

Comment: First ask yourself: "So what?" If there's no security being bypassed, money being lost, or data being written, then it probably doesn't matter if it's an AJAX connection  or not.

Comment: Note: the CodeIgnitor `is_ajax_request()` method just checks if the HTTP header `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` indicates that it was sent via xmlhttprequest thus can easily be spoofed... and during development you may want to access the (REST?) endpoint via the browser address bar just for testing. e.g. be careful how much logic you base on this "questionable" method.

Comment: I've often wondered this myself - I simply render a custom 404 view, but I've thought about catching it with Apache to reduce the number of CodeIgniter calls and thus, memory. I'd be interested to see a solution like this.

Comment: @JordanArseno i was wondering about throwing a 404 but was not sure that was the right fit.

Comment: i would use a redirect to a controller index and just have it refresh the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The golden rule is never trust user input

So regardless if the data comes from an ajax request - or is just sent to the function - your controller should assume it is tainted and do full validation, user authentication etc.

Therefore it doesnt really matter if someone ends up at that controller without an ajax request (either intentionally or accidentally) - so if the data they submit is valid, let it through.

If not - just throw a useful error message to the customer (especially if they got there accidentally).

Comment: yeah i am validating the inputs, but my thinking is if it is not coming in via ajax it is not the expected behavior from my app. so therefore i should just ignore it and not waste the time and resources processing the inputs. if i throw up an error should i return a status code? 200? reading the descriptions of the http status codes 403 seems like the appropriate code to return.